# New log file every time cron job runs

Tags: logging, cron

I have figured out how to output cron jobs to a log file using `>>` and providing a path to the log file. The `>>` appends log information to the existing file. How can I make it so the cron job creates a new log file every time it runs? (i.e. `rsync.log`, `rsync(1).log`, `rsync(2).log` -- ideally though I'd like the file name of the log to be something like `DD-MM-YY.log`).

I want a separate log file so this one log file doesn't get so huge and if/when we go to look if a file/folder was successfully backed up (I'm running an rsync command in the cron job) we don't have to comb through a MASSIVE log file.

Additionally, when the cron job is outputted to the log file, there are no time/date references. Example of my first log output:

```
**sending incremental file list**
**sent 78 bytes  received 11 bytes  35.60 bytes/sec**
**total size is 0  speedup is 0.00**
```

That's it. The timestamp on this logfile will keep changing every time the job is run, so we wouldn't even be able to tell what day that particular file/folder was copied via rsync. If I had a separate log file for every time the cron job ran, I could just open the log file for the particular date that it was created and view what was backed up.

My current cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * rsync -avz /home/me/test/ 1234@xxx-a123.rsync.net:test/ >>/home/me/cron_logs/homedir_backups/rsync.log 2>&1
```

I only have it set to 1 minute for testing purposes. Eventually this will only run daily at midnight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want time stamped logs, you add the string of a formatted date command, 
date +%d%y%m for day month year in number format.

You can use backtick to put the string in the cron:

```
~$ /home/me/cron_log-`/bin/date +%d-%m-%y`
```

So the file name will have the current date appended to it.  The backtick says "run this command and put the output here as a string".

Now the problem is that your directory might get huge and then you have to write a short script to delete them by time.  I have a script that reads the format and keeps X and deletes the rest but most people would just use "find" to delete by time older stuff, like logs that have mtime > 1 year.

Comment: Negative points for asking a question. Awesome. Just wanted to thank you very much Eugene for the backtick suggestion. That is exactly what I was looking for. I would vote you up but I'm not popular enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @franklin. After it told me "voting up requires 15 reputation" I rolled my eyes and closed the tab w/out looking back -- didn't even see the checkmark to mark as an answer.

Comment: @00fruX no problem. The reputation stuff can be challenging sometimes. But SO is a good community (in general). Good luck!