# How to save separate cron file in terminal without writing multiple lines

Tags: command-line, terminal, automation

I set it to run every minute. I have this:

```
* * * * * curl link > filepath/filename.json
```

However, the file is overwriting every minute.

I would need a file for each run, so 1440 files a day.

(I'm on a Mac if that makes any difference.)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26619961/3266847) to see how you can use the `date` command to create a unique filename every minute.

Comment: are logs accessible as separate json files?

Comment: If you do something like `curl link > filepath/$(date '+%%Y%%m%%d-%%H%%M%%S')-log.json` (notice double `%`, or cron gets confused), every minute's logs will be in a new file with a timestamp.